# Deinterleaving PCM (*.wav) stereo audio data

Tags: c++, encoding, pcm, vorbis

I understand that PCM data is stored as `[left][right][left][right]...`. Am trying to convert a stereo PCM to mono Vorbis (*.ogg) which I understand is achievable by halving the left and the right channels ((left+right)*0.5). I have actually achieved this by amending the encoder example in the libvorbis sdk like this,

```
#define READ 1024
signed char readbuffer[READ*4];
```

and the PCM data is read thus

```
fread(readbuffer, 1, READ*4, stdin)
```

I then halved the two channels,

```
buffer[0][i] = ((((readbuffer[i*4+1]<<8) | (0x00ff&(int)readbuffer[i*4]))/32768.f) + (((readbuffer[i*4+3]<<8) | (0x00ff&(int)readbuffer[i*4+2]))/32768.f)) * 0.5f;
```

It worked perfectly, but, I don't understand how they deinterleave the left and right channel from the PCM data (i.e. all the bit shifting and "ANDing" and "ORing").

Comment: How is readbuffer declared?

Comment: `#define READ 1024`
`signed char readbuffer[READ*4];`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A .wav file typically stores its PCM data in *little endian* format, with 16 bits per sample per channel. For the usual signed 16-bit PCM file, this means that the data is physically stored as

```
[LEFT LSB] [LEFT MSB] [RIGHT LSB] [RIGHT MSB] ...
```

so that every group of 4 bytes makes up a single stereo PCM sample. Hence, you can find sample `i` by looking at bytes `4*i` through `4*i+3`, inclusive.

To decode a single 16-bit value from two bytes, you do this:

```
(MSB << 8) | LSB
```

Because your read buffer values are stored as *signed* chars, you have to be a bit careful because both `MSB` and `LSB` will be sign-extended. This is undesirable for the LSB; therefore, the code uses

```
0xff & (int)LSB
```

to obtain the unsigned version of the low byte (technically, this works by upcasting to an int, and selecting the low 8 bits; an alternate formulation would be to just write `(uint8_t)LSB`).

Note that the MSBs are at indices 1 and 3, and the LSBs are at indices 0 and 2. So,

```
((readbuffer[i*4+1]<<8) | (0x00ff&(int)readbuffer[i*4]))
```

and

```
((readbuffer[i*4+3]<<8) | (0x00ff&(int)readbuffer[i*4+2]))
```

are just obtaining the values of the left and right channels as 16-bit signed values by using some bit manipulation to assemble the bytes into numbers.

Then, each of these values is divided by 32768.0. Note that a signed 16-bit value has a range of `[-32768, 32767]`. Thus, dividing by 32768 gives a range of approximately [-1, 1]. The two divided values are added to give a number in the range [-2, 2], and then the whole thing is multiplied by 0.5 to obtain the average (a floating-point value in the range [-1, 1]).

Comment: Thanks for your reply now I understand perfectly but another question pops up in my head. If the PCM is 8bit per sample per channels, does that means every 2 bytes makes up a single channel stereo sample? If that is so, how will the single 16bit value be gotten from the 1 byte (how will the padding be)

Comment: @Osofem - Yes to your first question.  As far as the 2nd question, what is the context ?  Are you trying to save into a WAV format (16 bit) some 8 bit PCM input data ?  If so you have two choices : save as 8 bit WAV or stretch the 8 bit into 16 bits. Either way pls post as separate question.